# Working with both SPM and Cocoapods in the same project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I have an Xcode project, consisting of a `swift packages`, a custom `cocoa pods` and one target dependency.

In workspace I have:

Project **ProfileUtil** - xcode project of type **Framework**. This project contains Firebase SPM dependencies

Project **DatabaseUtil** - xcode project of type **cocoapod**. This project contains Firebase pods dependencies

Project **MeditationApp** - Xcode project of type iOS Application. This is the main application, and it should include `ProfileUtil` as a **framework swift packages**, and `DatabaseUtil` as a **Pod**

When I try to compile the main iOS application, Im seeing errors like:

```
Error: Redefinition of module 'Firebase'

module Firebase {
  export *
  header "Firebase.h"
}
```

So that got me wondering if I can mix both SPM and Cocoapods in the same project if both uses the same library internally? *(I couldn't find any useful ressources online about that use case, which surprise me)*

Is there a bypass I could do to fix those, because as in the moment I have to keep my custom pod `DatabaseUtil` as a cocoapods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Firebase does not support being installed from both CocoaPods and Swift Package Manager in the same project. It might be possible to hack into place by hacking the workspace after a CocoaPods install, but it would be fragile.